# Upgrading from WSL1 to WSL2 - Will I lose files?

Tags: windows-subsystem-for-linux

If I upgrade from WSL1 to WSL2 will I still be able to access the filesystem in WSL1? I have a number of projects in WSL1 and also various virtual environments and environment variables set up in WSL1.

I'm wondering if I will have to start from scratch in WSL2?

Thanks

Answer (score 1):

> If I upgrade from WSL1 to WSL2 will I still be able to access the filesystem in WSL1?

Yes;  The upgrade process is seamless.  However, performing a proper backup of your files, is key to any procedure like this.

> I have a number of projects in WSL1 and also various virtual environments and environment variables set up in WSL1.

You should backup your projects in the event the upgrade process fails and makes the instance inaccessible.

> I'm wondering if I will have to start from scratch in WSL2?

No;  You can actually seamless transition between the two versions

Comment: I use `wsl --export` to get an archive of everything.  You will need to read the help for the options.    It works quite well to backup your environment and files.  I have not tried WSL1 export and WSL2 import.. but I am advising for the archive aspects, not the upgrade ones.